# How to implement option group in semantic-ui dropdown select

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I want to show categories and sub categories in a dropdown similar to select with option group in html.

How should I do it in semantic-ui. I didn't find any help on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this since the question is a bit old but I found this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLoanbwb/3/).

Basically you would use `div` instead of `select` and `option`.

#### HTML

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown multiple search optgroup">
    <div class="text">Select</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="ui horizontal divider">Optgroup 1</div>
        <div class="item">Option 1</div>
        <div class="item">Option 2</div>
        <div class="ui horizontal divider">Optgroup 2</div>
        <div class="item">Option 3</div>
        <div class="item">Option 4</div>
    </div>
</div
```

#### CSS

```
.dropdown.optgroup .divider {
    border-top: none !important;
}
```

#### Jquery

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```